# Mouse Hover on ListBoxItems of Custom ListBox

Tags: c#, mousehover, eventargs, listbox-control, ondrawitem

I have created a custom ListBox in c#.
I have drawn text and image on my custom ListBox using DrawItemEventArgs.
I want to fill a color in my rectangle(Item of ListBox) when mouse is hovered over it.
Is there a way for it using DrawItemEventArgs or otherwise.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should check on which item the mouse is. ListBox has a method to do such a check: IndexFromPoint https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfw3x8dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Now, when you have item index, you can get its rectangle using other method: GetItemRectangle https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.getitemrectangle(v=vs.110).aspx